# Submit a form on remote site via cURL and PHP, and download the file in response, remote page is html and https

Tags: php, regex, forms, curl, cross-domain

What I am trying is submit a form on remote site, the output of that form is a pdf file which I want to store to my site locally. I want to automate this via cron job, using PHP and cURL.

[image]

### Problems:

1. Remote site is https (even worse it is not properly setup)
2. The site is html and not PHP but it gives result as if PHP

### What I have tried so far

1. I used cURL in PHP but did not quite work. It simply submits a response which does not include the response from the form submission.
2. I tried to create remote form on my local host and when I submit form, it does return pdf file but this solution does not uses Curl and hence I cannot automate it.

### Code that I have tried so far

```
<?php 

// set post fields
$post = [
    'bench_sno' => '1',
    'causelist_date' => '2010-10-1',
    'btnSearch'   => 'Search Causelist',
];

$ch = curl_init('http://peshawarhighcourt.gov.pk/app/site/4/p/Causelists_List.html');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

// execute!
$response = curl_exec($ch);

// close the connection, release resources used
curl_close($ch);

// do anything you want with your response
//var_dump($response);
echo $response;

?>
```

When I just copy the remote form to my site and submit the form, it does work fine [Working Example](http://peshawar.co/utils/phc_form.html) but the problem is it does not work with cURL. I need to automate this task via cron job, any other solution if available, I can consider.

Comment: I feel this is not ethical, but what is the response you get in your cURL?

Comment: Also, is it `curl_init('http:` or `curl_init('https:` ?

Comment: [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) is very useful in such situations to debug. Maybe you are getting a 301 redirect, which browser handles just fine, hence making it working from your localhost.

Comment: The actual URL is `https://peshawarhighcourt.gov.pk/app/site/4/p/Causelists_List.html`, you can try it yourself (use only the last two fields, bench and date). The resposne form cURL is entire page but it does not have the form response, which is embedded in the page itself. Hence I can get the output of the form.

Comment: The above code can be tested [here](http://peshawar.co/utils/curl_post.php). Note that it fetches the entire page with out form feedback. Meaning the form is not properly posted? I tried https, same thing.

Comment: Try with `CURLOPT_SSl_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSl_VERIFYPEER` set to false.

Comment: @vivek_23 same response. The test url is just above you comment. Added this `
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSl_VERIFYHOST, CURLOPT_SSl_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Those are individual; settings. You would need to give them as separate commands. Like, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSl_VERIFYHOST, false);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSl_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Comment: Your curl code link says `Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /home2/pesh1/public_html/utils/curl_post.php on line 13`

Comment: @vivek_23 if you look at the form, there is a hidden field `<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://peshawarhighcourt.gov.pk:443/app/site/4/p/Causelists_List.html">
` could that be the culprit. [Form is located here](http://peshawar.co/utils/phc_form.html)

Comment: Not sure, I am not the dev who did it. You could add that in your post fields and try.

Comment: But, all in all, this isn't an ethical way. You better ask their devs to provide APIs for integration.

Comment: @vivek_23 yes that work. I am now getting response from the form but it just does not return the PDF file saying `There is no causelist uploaded for the selected date` getting closer.

Comment: This is public information, I am using it only to provide people a facility. Here they wont give you API etc.

Comment: OK it is all fine now, I was making a typo in fact. Next step it to get link of the pdf file. Have to explore that.

Answer (score 0):

As came under discussion in the question itself, and pointed out by @vivek_23 to include it in the fields, the form now works

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://peshawarhighcourt.gov.pk:443/app/site/4/p/Causelists_List.html">
```